# Windows 7 taking more space than Vista?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I've just done an upgrade from Windows Vista Home to Windows 7 Home. I had previously done a backup of all the files i needed to keep ( pics, music, emails,...) on another computer.

In all, the backup files amount to about 50GB. The computer in question has a 160GB hd, but for some reason, Win 7 only sees it as having 136GB. I know the actual size of a disk is smaller than the spec, but by this much? Doesn't sound right to me...

Space was not an issue while it was running Vista.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The difference will be decimal GB versus binary GB and file system formatting/overhead.  HDD manufacturers always quote sizes in decimal units.

1 GB  (decimal) = 1,000,000,000

1 GiB (binary)  = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1,073,741,824

So, 160,000,000,000 / 1,073,741,824 = 149,011,611,938.

The difference between 136 GiB and 149 GiB is probably the file system overhead plus the installation size for W7 - doesn't seem unreasonable.

Remember too that the size that the files require on disk is greater than their total size in bytes due to disk allocation units; each file is rounded up to the DAU.

Comment: If the backed up docs only use around 50GB, then we have to assume that the OS is using the rest? I haven't installed any big software yet either...

Win 7 can't possibly be using 90GB?

Comment: @Logikdev: Do you have a typo in your question? I make 160 - 136 = 24, not 140+?

Comment: My Vista C:\Windows directory takes about 16 GiB.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find at the "[Engineering Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/)" blog a nice article describing their effort regarding [**Disk Space**](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2008/11/19/disk-space.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Actually just found out what's going on.

When installing Windows 7 as an upgrade, it keeps the old OS on the hdd in the windows.old folder. This folder used up 75GB in my case.

Here's the way to get rid of this folder:

[Removing windows.old folder](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/a88eca16-2cc6-421c-94fc-f444b9efa889)